# Magento 2 Breadcrumbs show wrong on product page because of cache

Tags: product, magento2.3, category, catalog, breadcrumbs

Magento 2.3.5 and 2.4 both versions have these issues.

The same product is assigned in two categories.

Suppose two main categories -

**Category One** and **Category Two**

Category One subcategories are **Category OneA** and **Category OneB**

Category Two subcategories are **Category TwoA** and **Category TwoB**

Product name is **Sample product**

**Sample product** is assigned on these two categories **Category OneB** and **Category TwoA**

If we are coming from a Navigation step by step **Category One** -> **Category OneB** then Breadcrumbs **should be like** this on the product detail page

**Home->Category One->Category OneB->Sample product**

If we are coming from a Navigation step by step **Category Two** -> **Category TwoB** then Breadcrumbs **should be like** this on the product detail page

**Home->Category Two->Category TwoA->Sample product**

But right now it is always coming from the cache, sometimes show

**Home->Category One->Category OneB->Sample product**
in both path

Sometimes show
**Home->Category Two->Category TwoA->Sample product**

How can we show breadcrumbs proper ?

Comment: Magento does cache for the unique URL, I belive your url is same for both cases. Check the URL in both cases, usually magento generates the URLs for all the associated categories unless disabled from admin configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Disable cache for product page. But that is bad idea. Only option is to fetch breadcrumbs using js and ajax, because that is not cached. In that call check what is current category (it will be that category, that came from), check if product assigned to that category (could be customer used direct link and current category won't be assigned to product) and return breadcrumb for that category. Of course customer can come direct to that page, then there is will be no current category (or it could be some non related category). Then just show first or last category breadcrumb, or none, as you decide.

Comment: Thanks for the reply is there any other method or code to resolve this issue?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Don;t know other way. It is cache, that is problem. So you should turn it off for product page or use ajax. If there was only one category for product, then it would be cached and no problems. But you need to change breadcrumbs, depending on from where customer comes. So no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would forget the idea of changing breadcrumbs in the  HTML. From an SEO perspective, you're much better off with there only ever being 1 path to the product in a PIP breadcrumb. I wrote a module to do away with the default.

THEN, if you want a true user path in there, I'd use javascript to put the category URL into the breadcrumb, possibly utilising a cookie to store the last X pages/URLs.